# rails - hide 'source of your encoding' from terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ROR and I"m having trouble with all the text that rails spits to the terminal window. Primarily, the html from my web pages get repeated in the terminal window and I'm really just wanting to see the important stuff like sql queries and error messages. I'm wasting a lot of time scrolling throughout the terminal window trying to find what I need b/c of all the HTML that fills up the screen.

Is there an option to disable the 'source of your encoding' output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could raise your log level
The rails guide gives a good example
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels
Make sure if you are in development to change it in `config/environments/development.rb`

I don't know if this will really solve your problem though because I am unsure of exactly what output you are looking for. A higher log level may throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: This is a great link. But you're correct that by going from debug level to info level that in addition to getting rid of the extraneous text that I don't want to see, I also get rid of seeing the sql queries that are generated (which I really do like seeing).

Comment: I highly recommend reading through all of those guides, then later when you know more, read them again. I always find new goodies.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use a tool like tmux in your terminal. It has a great, simple search system. And besides that it is great.